# jShowOff Slide Show Can't Click in Center of Slide

Tags: javascript, slideshow, jshowoff

See the "Re-styled Thumbnail Demo" (bottom right) on the home page for this,
http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/

Put your cursor at the top middle of the slide and you can can click. 
Put your cursor at the middle and there is no click available.

I believe the prev/next arrows are to blame. Both are enclosed in the same < p > tag. I tried adding a z-index without success.

This is a problem because our linked slides are not large, and there is not much clickable area above and below the prev and next arrows. Besides, most people would click in the middle of the slide.

Can you tell me how to fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Root cause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlAcZ.png)

CSS line 448 - 449

```
.thumbFeatures p.jshowoff-controls {
    background: none;
    height: 0px; /* I am the cause */
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 150;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that the z-index suggested by Timd3v, and it doesn't work - the arrows disappear. Here's a code pen to work with [https://codepen.io/iamalta/pen/NWKBwJG](https://codepen.io/iamalta/pen/NWKBwJG)

Comment: Hi, I noticed it too after testing apologies. Here is the working version now https://codepen.io/timd3v/pen/mdbjXVR

Changes:
Setting the height to 0 on CSS line 449 seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.